# File Pods/Realm/core/realm-monorepoxcframework/watchos-arm64 i38 6 x86 64-simulatoz/librealn-monorepo.a isexceeds GitHub's file size limit

Tags: swift, realm

when trying to push my branch, which contains realm database,
after about 25 minutes of waiting after git push, im getting the following:
[image]

I added my pods and those links to .gitignore, but nothing changes:
gitignore file:

```
Pods/Realm/core/realm-monorepo.xcframework/*
Pods/Realm/core/realm-monorepo.xcframework/watchos-arm64_i386_x86_64simulator//librealm-monorepo.a
xcuserdata/
Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
Pods/
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I am missing something but Githubs recommended limit if 50Mb and if you're pushing up 68Mb of data - that's not going to work. Over 100 is simply past the allowed limit. Do you need to include the Realm repo or can you just upload your code?

Comment: I added it in .gitignore, but still facing this issue

Comment: Per my above comment - why are the Realm libraries being included? Those are already on Git so you could just upload your code.